# How to define a pointer to a class member function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Related to C++ Basics.
I am creating a singly linked list.

```
class Linked_List
{
public: Linked_List();
    ~Linked_List();
        //Member Functions
    struct node* getHead(void);
private:
    struct node{
        int d;
        struct node* next;
    }*head;
};
struct node (Linked_List::*getHead)(void)
{
    return head;
}
```

I am getting this error:

> "error C2470: 'getHead' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body".

I tried to search in google but of no use. Any suggestions plz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a pointer to member function, you just want to provide a *definition* for that function:

```
Linked_List::node* Linked_List::getHead()
{ 
    return head;
}
```

Also notice, that the `struct` keyword is unnecessary in the function definition, while you have to qualify the name of the struct `node` with the name of the class in the scope of which it is defined.

Also, the `void` keyword to specify an empty argument list is unnecessary. I therefore suggest you to rewrite the class definition as follows:

```
class Linked_List
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        int d;
        struct node* next;
    };
    node *head;
public:
    Linked_List();
    ~Linked_List();
    node* getHead();
};
```

Comment: @bash0r: No idea. Ask the OP :-)

Comment: Linked_List::node* Linked_List::getHead() worked Thanks :)           BTW i know that void and struct keywords are unnecessary :)           int d is for data of a node in linked list